# c# WebRequest cookies not working

Tags: c#, streamreader, webrequest

I am trying to get my c# console application to check if the credentials supplied are correct. But when I try it the web page gives a error:

```
<div id="login_error">  <strong>ERROR</strong>: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must <a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Cookies">enable cookies</a> to use WordPress.<br />
```

This is my code:

```
     static bool SendRequest(string Username, string Password, string URL) {

        string formUrl = URL; 
        string formParams = string.Format("log={0}&pwd={1}&wp-submit={2}&redirect_to={3}&testcookie={4}", Username, Password, "Log In", "http://localhost/wp-admin/", "1");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

        string pageSource;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Console.Write(pageSource);

        return true;
    }
```

I think the problem is that the cookies are not working but I have no clue how to fix this.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You're not setting a [CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) to your `HttpWebRequest`, thus the default is set to `null` which means the client won't accept cookies.

CookieContainer from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx)

> The CookieContainer property provides an instance of the
>   CookieContainer class that contains the cookies associated with this
>   request.
>
> CookieContainer is **null** by default. You must assign a
>   CookieContainer object to the property to have cookies returned in the
>   Cookies property of the HttpWebResponse returned by the GetResponse
>   method.

You must set a new `CookieContainer` before getting a response from the server.

```
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
((HttpWebRequest)req).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
// Rest of the code here..
```

Comment: I have edited my code and added the cookiecontainer but i still get the error.

Comment: @BruteFlame, If you're getting an error, it's definitely not Cookies errors, It's working to me perfectly. Please make sure what's your new error is.